# JQuery confirm password validation not working

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I am using a jquery validation plugin for checking form validation.
here is code

#### New User? Register Here!

Username 
 
 Password 

 Confirm Password 

 Email 

Submit

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("word_check", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/i.test(value);
}, "special characters/spaces not allowed");
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules:{
           "Username":{
            required: true,     
            minlength:5,
            word_check : true
          },
        "password":{
             required:true,
             minlength:5
        },
        "Confirm_Password":{
            required:true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        "email":{
             required: true,
             email: true
        }
    }    
  });  
 });
```

it's working but it always show "password not match error, instead of same password"

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `password` field has `id="password" name="password"` and the 2nd field `"Confirm_Password"` has `name="Confirm_Password"`

Comment: I've tested your code and its fine http://jsfiddle.net/63fS4/1/ check your jquery validation plugin version and jquery version

Comment: yeah it works fine but couldn't find my maistake can you pelase look into my form code.